# I want to select UserId that contains value and does not contain value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table M_In 
It has two columns  UserId,MeFr
I want to select UserId that contains value (*123*) and does not contain value (*456*) or other value

Example table M_In

```
UserId  MeFr
------------
100     *123*
100     *456*
100     *123*
200     *123*
200     *456*
300     *123*
```

Expected output

```
UserId  MeFr
------------
300     *123*
```

I want to use this method Example

Example

```
Select * from     
  (select i.*,                                   
         row_number() over (partition by UserId order by UserId ) as rn
  from M_In i 
   ) i 
   left join  
   (select o.*,                                   
         row_number() over (partition by UserId order by UserId ) as rn
  from M_In o
  ) o  on o.UserId = i.UserId
 where not EXISTS
```

Comment: Please explain what does *UserId that contains value and does not contain value* mean.

Comment: thank you for reply
I want to select UserId that contains value (*123*) and does not contain value (*456*) or other value

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = '123'`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use make use of NOT EXISTS ()

```
SELECT *
FROM   M_In m
WHERE  m.MeFr = 123
AND    NOT EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   M_In x
           WHERE  x.UserId = m.UserId
           AND    x.MeFr   <> 123
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple join should do the job here:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM   M_In m
join M_In m1 on m.UserId = m1.UserId
WHERE  m.MeFr = 123 and m1.MeFr <> 123
```